# linux shell script to copy directory tree and link files

Tags: linux, shell, hyperlink, directory

I would like to be able to create a copy of a directory tree and soft link the files on it.

For example, from

```
/home/user/origin/a/sub/file.txt
```

I would like to get

```
/home/user/destination/a/sub/file.txt
```

being this one a link to the original file.txt.

I tested with

```
find /home/user/origin/ -type d -printf "mkdir -vp '/home/user/destination%p'\n" -o -type f -printf "ln -vs '%p' '/home/user/destination%p'\n" | sh
```

but it has two problems:

1. I'd like to copy from origin to destination, and it copies from origin to `/home/user/destination/home/user/origin`. It is not a biggie, as I can move that afterwards
2. If the file name is something like

> In Fifty Years We'll All Be Chicks.txt
>   
>   It stops working because the '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, it seems easier to just use `-exec`

```
find /home/user/origin/ \
-type d -exec sh -c 'mkdir -v "/home/user/destination/${0#/home/user/origin/}"' {} \; \
-o \
-type f -exec sh -c 'ln -vs "$0" "/home/user/destination/${0#/home/user/origin/}"' {} \;
```

Note `-or` having lower precedence than the implied `-and`'s is important here.